# NSException Error - Swift 4

Tags: ios, firebase, xcode9, swift4, nsexception

stack overflow community. Please don't mark this question as a duplicate as I have seen all the other posts regarding this and have pretty much gone through most of the famous solutions.

Currently, I have some code that allows a user to send messages to a group and also change the group thumbnail and title. However, upon the user doing any of this, my code crashes. I am storing my data in firebase (the data is being successfully uploaded). The problem began when I upgraded from swift 3 to swift 4. Also, this is the specific error I am getting:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here are some solutions/methods I have tried to solve my problem:

1. I have outruled that this is an outlet problem as the view controller is programmatically created.
2. I tried adding an exception breakpoint but it didn't show me any specific lines of code for where the crash occurred.
3. I have also tried cleaning, re-building, and closing Xcode however that doesn't work as well.
4. I don't think its a problem with uploading data to firebase as I am able to in other parts of my app.
5. I have also tried scrolling through the threads to get a deeper understanding of where the crash occurs, however that has not been of much help.

Here is a picture of my console output:
[image: The main thread ui stuff is entered into the console is not triggered by the crash. The only output triggered by the crash is the error message above.]

Here is the code I use to update the collection view:

```
func observeConversationMessagesWithConversationId(conversationId: String) {
    Database.database().reference().child("conversation-messages").child(conversationId).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let messages = ConversationMessages(snapshot: snapshot) {

            self.conversationMessages.append(messages)

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()

                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(item: self.conversationMessages.count - 1, section: 0)
                self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
            })
        }
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```

Here is my podfile

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Please note that I would have added some code but I have no clue where the error occurs.

Comment: can you please show the screenshot error message?what does it say in console?

Comment: I just posted a screenshot. Please read the caption to understand the console output a bit more.

Comment: Ok what I have understood is that you are updating your UI on a background thread like in some callback you are changing your UI, please check in your code

Comment: Yes I do change my ui. When a message is sent I update a collection view to display that message. If a user is sending the first message to this group it works fine. However, if it is any message other than the second it crashes

Comment: can you please show the code?

Comment: i just added it.

Comment: Ok are you using googlemaps in your project?

Comment: Yes I am but google maps does not have anything to do with the messaging part of the project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156610/discussion-between-rohan-vasishth-and-3stud1ant3).

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know where the error occurs, it might be a good idea to place a few breakpoints in your code so you can pinpoint the crash. Then it will be a lot easier to fix the error when you know the exact line where it happens.

I had the same crash and it was related to `UIVisualEffectView`, and specifically with adding a subview to it instead of adding it to its `.contentView`.

If that is your case too, you can find more details **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46739244/611879)**.

Good luck bug hunting.

Comment: Well I figured out the error and it begins to work if I turn the objc inference property on. Which I realize is a bad idea so do you have a new suggestion?